# Selling .net controls (help)

Tags: .net, controls

Is there a site made for selling .net controls?  I can't seem to find anything.  I was wondering if somebody could please point me towards a site.  I'd rather it not be a site that requires giving out the source code (include them anyways if you can).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to sell .NET controls on such a site?  Why not just sell them they way you would sell any other piece of software?

Comment: Step 1: Buy a domain. Step 2: Create a website. Step 3: Integrate an eCommerce solution. Step 4: Sell your controls.

Comment: You can't make any money selling controls unless you're one of the big component vendors that sell packages of them.  With source code.  So no.

Comment: @Brian, if I wanted to do that, I would go ahead and create my own .net control selling site.  I was simply asking if there was a site already in existence that would allow me to sell controls and other application components.

Comment: I guess he's after the .net equivalent of http://www.turbosquid.com/

Comment: @DalexL Sorry, I forgot to put on the closing `</sarcasm>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one site [CodeCanyon.com](http://codecanyon.net/?ref=psalaciak), however selling .net controls there is not as common as JS, PHP etc. 
PS: excuse me for the referral link

Comment: Hmmm... I might just have to deal with it.  Thanks!  That looks like something I might like :)

Comment: Referral link eh ;)  That is a-ok =P

Answer (score 1):

See the [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5b0%5d.Type=RootCategory&f%5b0%5d.Value=controls&f%5b0%5d.Text=Controls&sortBy=Ratings).

Comment: It looks like a directory. DalexL would still need to have his own website = domain, server and integrated payment gateway = costs

Comment: @Piotr: did you notice the "[Upload](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/upload)" button?

Comment: This looks interesting as well.  I might have to utilize this as well.  Thanks!